# Can't import annotations from __future__

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, future

When running the statement

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 125, in compile
    _optimize=optimize)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 735, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "./prog.py", line 1
    from __future__ import annotations
    ^
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 129, in compile
    raise py_exc
py_compile.PyCompileError:   File "./prog.py", line 1
    from __future__ import annotations
                                     ^
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Looking at your error traceback, it looks like you are using `python 3.5`. Is that the case?

If so, then the error happens because according to [PEP-563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7) the import of `__future__` `annotations` is available starting with `Python 3.7`.

I did not find any hints that this will be backported to previous versions, but I might have missed that.

Comment: Thanks. The problem fixed after installing Python 3.7.

Comment: This future feature is also missing in Python 3.6. Why isn't it back ported? If I use annotations, they are widely supported in 3.7, so no need for a future. If I run my code on an older Python, both, the annotations and the future are not supported. So why this future?

Comment: Mabe because those annotations are planned for Python 4.0.

Comment: the future import is not about annotations, it's about postponed evaluation of annotations.

Comment: For anyone coming along now, this appears to have been back-ported to 3.6.9

Comment: I don't think it is. Running Python 3.6.9 and I am still getting `SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined`

Comment: Is Python 3.7 tested with Ubuntu 16? It doesn't seem to be an `apt` package.

Comment: @personal_cloud I am not sure that I understand your question/comment; the `__future__ annotations` is a Python package and not an Ubuntu/`apt` package. Also, this `__future__ annotations` package is included in the standard Python installation (depending on the version) and as far as I know it is not available as a separate package for optional installation.

Answer (score 1):

If it happens with Python 3.6, do:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```