# SyntaxError: future feature google_type_annotations is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

```
from __future__ import google_type_annotations
```

[I installed python 3.7 as it was suggested in this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889746/cant-import-annotations-from-future/52890129)

I get the following error when I run the file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_classifier_with_tfhub.py", line 21, in <module>
import classifier_utils
File "/ALBERT/classifier_utils.py", line 19
from __future__ import google_type_annotations
^
SyntaxError: future feature google_type_annotations is not defined
```

Comment: I tried using 3.7.5 and 3.6.8.

Comment: Are you sure you're running your program with Python 3.7+?

Comment: Yes, I just rechecked it. it is 3.7+

Comment: That error message is from line 19. Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, there may be multiple versions installed, output the Python version from inside that code. BTW: The post you linked was about a different feature, so the version mentioned there is irrelevant. Which PEP corresponds to the future you're trying to import?

Comment: https://github.com/google-research/ALBERT/blob/master/classifier_utils.py here is the link to the code which I am using.

Comment: No, you need to extract a [mcve] and include that inline in your question.

Comment: `google_type_annotations` is not part of standard Python. Read the [documentation of `pytype`](https://google.github.io/pytype/user_guide.html)

Comment: @MuhammadHanifSarwari I think you haven't installed. https://github.com/google/pytype. Installing that will fix your issue