# Getting SyntaxError: future feature google_type_annotations is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm running python 3.7.5. The line:

```
from __future__ import google_type_annotations
```

Throws the following error:

```
SyntaxError: future feature google_type_annotations is not defined
```

Another S/O post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369532/syntaxerror-future-feature-google-type-annotations-is-not-defined) notes this problem - the comments imply that installing `pytype` would solve the issue.

-- I installed pytype, however the problem remains.

I also took a brief look at these logs from this website: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/google-cloud-sdk/?O=10&PP=10, which mentions the problem in passing and led me to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146012762. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around, this seems to be a feature from a patch released by Google to backport Python 3 style type annotations to older versions of Python. It should be safe to delete that line from your code if you're already running a version of Python 3.

Comment: The error's actually being thrown from my [gin-config](https://github.com/google/gin-config) installation, it seems. I may as well open an issue there.

Comment: While not a permanent fix, I dug into the source and commented out the offending imports before building gin again. It seems to work fine now : )