# SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined

Tags: python, conda

I am try to run code

```
sh run.sh
```

and it showed me the error

```
File "/anaconda3/envs/_galaxy_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/filelock/__init__.py", line 8
    from __future__ import annotations
    ^
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

I saw some solutions indicated that I need to update my python version, but I am in a python verion 3.9.7.

```
(py39) KedeMacBook-Pro:~ ke$ python --version
Python 3.9.7
```

However, in the error code it showed a python veriosn of 3.6. So, I am not sure where went wrong. Why it is not using the python envrionment that I have? Please help, thank you.

Comment: `from __future__ import annotations` is only available from Python3.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't import annotations from \_\_future\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889746/cant-import-annotations-from-future)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the error, it looks like your code is using Python 3.6 and not Python 3.9. This import is available starting from Python 3.7. Check `run.sh` to make sure it is referencing the right python interpreter.

I'd also recommend using a [virtual env](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) using the python version you require and running your script inside that.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked after I created the virtualenv. This error troubled me for weeks, thank you for save my day. haha

Comment: @keee not a problem :)

Comment: I did that and now I have a different error module 'packaging.version' has no attribute 'LegacyVersion'