# gradio importing error on jupyter notebook: SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined

Tags: jupyter-notebook, fast-ai, gradio

So I am pretty new to the ML world and currently following fastai's deep learning course. I tried to import gradio on my local machine's Jupyter. (using mamba). Whenever I try to import the module as

```
import gradio as gr
```

it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/eren/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-5-43eca54f7d45>", line 1, in <module>
    import gradio as gr

  File "/home/eren/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gradio/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gradio.components as components

  File "/home/eren/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gradio/components.py", line 5
    from __future__ import annotations
                                      ^
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

Any idea about what I need to do is appreciated.

I tried installing gradio in the environment, the error:

```
Looking for: ['gradio']

conda-forge/linux-64                                          No change
conda-forge/noarch                                  10.9MB @   2.1MB/s  5.3s

Pinned packages:
  - python 3.10.*


Could not solve for environment specs
Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested gradio

The environment can't be solved, aborting the operation
```

Answer (score 0):

From the traceback it looks like you're using python version 3.6.

At the moment, gradio supports python versions 3.7 and above (as seen [here](https://pypi.org/project/gradio/))

> Prerequisite: Gradio requires Python 3.7 or higher, that's all!

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52890129/1382495) answer, the future feature `annotations` is only implemented in python 3.7 onwards.